# MSBuild - Nest an external file (file outside of the project folder) into a file in the project folder

Tags: wcf, iis, msbuild

I have the following scenario:

I have 2 projects:

- Proj1
- Proj2

Each of these projects needs access to a similar service (FooService) so I wrote up the Foo.svc and Foo.svc.cs files and put them in a directory that was outside of both of the project directories.

I then edited my Proj1.csproj file to do the following:

Foo.svc

This works fine in terms of editing and compiling the code, however I can't access the service: http://localhost/Proj1/Foo.svc << This does not exist (because the actual Foo.svc file is not in the Project directory).

So instead I copied the Foo.svc file inside each of the Projects and just left the code-behind file (Foo.svc.cs) in the common directory. However, now Visual Studio complains that "The parent file, 'Foo.svc', for file '..\Common\Foo.svc.cs' cannot be found in the project file. Probably because it is looking for the 'Foo.svc' file relative to the code-behind file?

Foo.svc

Is there any way to do what I'm looking for... keeping the code-behind outside of both project directories (so they can both link to it) and somehow have svc files that are accessible in my IIS on localhost and have it so that the code-behind file folds into the svc file in Visual Studio?

Comment: What about making a third project with the services, and including that project in both solutions?

Comment: Thought about that, but i'm actually going to have a lot more than 2 project files and each of them can either contain or not contain a mix of the services. For example, FooService might be used in Proj1-5 but not Proj6, BarService might be used in Proj1 and 4. There would be too many permutations needed and I'd just end up sticking each of the services in it's own project and referencing projects instead of including the files.

Comment: Is there a problem with including FooService in Proj6 if it's not used?  You could just one have service project that has the kitchen sink...

Comment: Yea, I have the Proj1-6 because each customer requires a different mix and match of services. If I include everything in one project and deploy that project to multiple customers then I'll have multiple customers with services exposed that don't make sense for that customer. The problem is really an aesthetic thing... I'd like for my csproj to fold the code-behind file into the svc file. It still functions even if I don't, but it's a bit annoying to not have it fold in.

Comment: Then it sounds like each project should have it's own services included in the project... they aren't really separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is altering your MSBuild file (also known as a csproj file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx)

I tried to simulate what you're doing and I don't think there is a solution that would fit what you want. You're right, your project will work just fine, but aesthetically you can't have a file external to the project directory nested to a file inside of the project directory.